# If statement that contains <> to condition not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues with this code whereby the columns still display despite not meeting the IF condition:

`If CBool(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(j), "<>0"))`

The code loops through columns and only displays columns that have values > 0. I do not know if the issue is with `j` or with the `CBool` condition itself. I would like some help as I really need this code for my excel as it would be then much easier and useful to analyze! Thank you.

```
Sub TestPasteColumnData3()

    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim j As Long

    With Worksheets("WF - L12 (3)")
        lastcol = .Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For j = 3 To lastcol
            'change >0 to <>0 and 3 to j
            If CBool(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(j), "<>0")) Then
                .Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet 1").Columns(j) 'Dont delete, this code works
            Else
                MsgBox ("No Value")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your data contain negative values? Are all values numeric? Does it contain any blank cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CountIf function will count ANYTHING, including blank cells, in the range if it is not equal to 0, which will cause your

```
CBool(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(j), "<>0"))
```

to be TRUE if you have anything other than a column full of 0's (with no blanks)

You might try

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Columns(j)) > 0 Then
    .Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet 1").Columns(j) 'Dont delete, this code works
Else
    MsgBox ("No Value")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

which will give you any column that has anything that is greater than 0, but still account for any blanks (or otherwise) you may have in the column.

Comment: That is a pretty smart idea! Tried it but now it jumps to "No value" :/

Comment: However the code does work when i insert random column values. So i guess the issue is with j again

Comment: It sounds like there is a column somewhere causing the error - are you able to go into the excel sheet and sum all of the columns to see which one(s) are causing the error?

Comment: i summed all of them. it is not an issue

Comment: Does the code work if you hardwire lastcol to, say, 5?

Comment: I think I see the problem, now.  If there is a column that sums to 0, the program will end because the conditional statement will be false.  If you take out Exit Sub, the program should continue to run after you get the message "No Value"

Comment: I tried and it works now. However it is looping column by column hence i have to constantly click on the no value , every time the column has a sum of 0 it keeps popping the value box. Is there anyway for it to loop all columns in one run ?

Comment: Why not take the msgbox  out as well?

Answer (score 1):

`WorksheetFunction.CountIf` will return a *count of cells that satisfy a given condition*. You're converting that *count* to a Boolean - that will evaluate to `True` for any non-zero result.

You need to compare that count to *something* e.g. `> 0` to result in a *Boolean expression* (then you can remove the `CBool`) to achieve the expected result.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(j), "<>0") > 0 Then
```

But then, *if any non-zero integer converts to `True`*, this code is equivalent (albeit less explicit about what it's doing):

```
If CBool(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(j), "<>0")) Then
```

Therefore, that condition cannot be the problem.

You need to place a break point (<kbd>F9</kbd>) before the loop, run the code, and step through (<kbd>F8</kbd>) to see what's going on. The problem might be with the usage of `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` against your specific worksheet data.

Comment: There is blank cells in some columns could that be the reason?

Comment: @Niva are there non-numeric values? If you use that `CountIf` formula on the worksheet itself, do you get the result you're expecting? Does the VBA code return the same result?

Comment: Tried it on another sheet with no blank cells and just numbers with a few 0s in some columns..It still displays all the columns

Comment: it has some title headers in btw thou